# Chrome not using configured proxy

Tags: linux, google-chrome, windows-10, proxy, squid

I am fighting and losing trying to set a proxy in Chrome that is signed into a school account. When I sign out of the account the proxy works, when I sign back in the proxy seems to stop working. Now I have gone over all of the extensions to see if anything is controlling the outbound connections, I don't see anything that stands out.

I have even set the proxy as transparent and set a nat rule on my firewall... and yet this STILL seems to bypass the proxy settings.

I am at a loss as to what to do next on how to force Chrome to use this proxy.

Squid Proxy IP: 10.0.0.2 Port: 3128

What I have tried:

*Windows: chrome.exe --proxy-server="10.0.0.2:3128"*
*Linux: chrome --proxy-server="10.0.0.2:3128"*
*NAT on Firewall*
*Windows: Internet Options: Set Proxy*
*Linux: /etc/environment global proxy settings*

None of the above have worked once Chrome is signed into the School Chrome account. Any help would be grateful! Thanks.

Edit #1
Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Chrome should definitely be using the proxy that's set in Internet Options of IE.  Going to `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` and `chrome://net-internals/#events` might assist in troubleshooting.

Comment: OK, I checked this and and see the post above for a screenshot...

Comment: So you mention a "school Chrome account", do you mean a GAFE (Google Apps for Education) account?  If that's the case, it might be inheriting settings from the Google Apps console, do you have control over the Google Apps Admin Console?

Comment: I assume that is what it is... The kids each have one for school and no I don't have access to the console, that would be the school they go to.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure you're going to be able to get around it if that's the case.

Comment: I will try and reach out to the system admin for the school district to see what other options I have. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31209/discussion-between-metalcated-and-josh).